# Even with "System Context Without Sharing" subflow, getting INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: visual-workflow, apex-managed-sharing

**Bottom line up front:** If the running user is internal, we have no issues. If the running user is a Customer user, we get the INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, despite calling a sub-flow with *System Context Without Sharing*. I expected using this context on a Sub-Flow would eliminate the running user from consideration, but it does not.

**Why does the initiating user matter with this Flow context?**

Scenario:

- A Customer Community/Experience User creates a new Case from the Experience site.
- A Record Triggered Flow (Before-Save) assigns the Case (based on type of Case) to a Partner Community/Experience User as the Case Owner.
- I need to also Share the Case using Manual Sharing with a group of Partner Community/Experience Users who are already part of a Public Group.

When I launch a record-triggered Flow (*After-Save*), the Customer user lacks permission to create a new Case Share record, so I am now running a sub-flow with "*System Context Without Sharing--Access All Data*" context. The sub-flow looks up the Public Group Id and the Case Id and creates a Manual Share record.

However, I get a failure with INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error even though it should be in System Context. The debug email indicates the "Current User" is the Customer User.

If I test using an internal Salesforce User to create the Case or manually trigger the sub-flow, I don't get the error and the Share is created properly, so I assume this has to do with Customer User permissions.

**More Details:**

- The Case is shared with the Customer user using the Experience Settings >Sharing Sets (Where User:Contact = Case:Contact)
- We look up the Public Group that the Case will be shared with using a Related Custom Object (Property__c)
- The Sub-Flow gets the IDs passed to it without issue, but fails to insert the Share record.

**Debug Email Log (IDs are obfuscated):**

```
Flow Details

Flow API Name: OBJ_Support_Ticket_Case_Created
Type: Autolaunched Flow
Version: 8
Status: Active
Org: Suite Management Franchising (00D1I___________)
Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: OBJ Support Ticket (Case) Created 3/2/2022, 5:52 PM
Interview GUID: 5252d9db503c16737537159a0ce17_________-542b
Current User: Betty Rubble (0051I00000_____)
Start time: 3/2/2022, 5:52 PM
Duration: 0 seconds
How the Interview Started
Scheduled Path: Wait_1_Minute
Betty Rubble (0051I00000_____) started the flow interview.
API Version for Running the Flow: 54
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
$Record = Case (5008W00000________)
SUBFLOW: Share Case w Property Group
Enter flow Share_Case_with_Property_Group version 6.
API Version for Running the Flow: 54
Inputs:
caseID = {!$Record.Id} (5008W00000________)
propertyID = {!$Record.Property__c} (a021I000006_______)
GET RECORDS: Find Group ID
Find one Group record where:
DeveloperName Equals {!propertyID} (a021I000006_______)
Result
Successfully found record.
{!groupID} = 00G1I000002Z______
ASSIGNMENT: Add Group to Manual Share
{!caseSharePublicGroup.UserOrGroupId} Equals {!groupID}
{!caseSharePublicGroup.RowCause} Equals Manual
{!caseSharePublicGroup.CaseId} Equals {!caseID}
{!caseSharePublicGroup.CaseAccessLevel} Equals Edit
Result
{!caseSharePublicGroup.CaseAccessLevel} = "Edit"
{!caseSharePublicGroup.RowCause} = "Manual"
{!caseSharePublicGroup.UserOrGroupId} = "00G1I000002Z______"
{!caseSharePublicGroup.CaseId} = "5008W00000________"
CREATE RECORDS: Create Share Record
Create CaseShare records using the values that are stored in {!caseSharePublicGroup}.
Variable Values
[UserOrGroupId=00G1I000002Z______,RowCause=Manual,CaseId=5008W00000________,CaseAccessLevel=Edit]
Result
Failed to create records.
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Salesforce Error ID: 277280955-1855814 (175474861)
```

Comment: what license type does your experience cloud user has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that to use the ShareRecords or Manual Share, you should have the license type of [Customer Community Plus](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335312&type=1) for your Experience Cloud User.

Customer Community Licenses can only use Sharing set to share the records

Also System Context does not imply your Current user becomes automated user. It will still be the running User, except it will have additional privileges but not something to bypass License limitation.

> Even though the flow runs in System Mode, Sharing Settings will be checked. Only CRUD and FLS will not be checked against the user.

Comment: Thank you. We do have Customer Community, not Plus. However, we are not sharing WITH the Customer User, we are sharing with a Public Group. And the sharing works as intended when initiated by an internal Salesforce licensed user.

Comment: @AndrewMondy Thats expected behavior as the license itself wont have access to the sharing table

Comment: So even if I run the sharing sub-flow as "System Context Without Sharing" it still keeps the running user? Why is this?

Comment: It runs in System Mode or System Context. Does not mean it will not check for Sharing settings and license limitations. Note running user will still be your actual user with elevated permissions

Comment: Also once the case owner changes, the customer user itself does not have access to it any more and this can also cause the error.

Comment: Would using a Trigger instead of a Record Triggered flow cause the sharing to be done as System instead of the User?

Comment: @AndrewMondy I think the trigger might work. One thing you can try in trigger is calling an async-like queueable to insert share records. Even in Flows, I would try going asynchronous to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Yes, good point. I didn't mention, but I did use an Asynchronous path for the subflow, hoping that would help.